# change line width in parallel coordinate plot in R

Tags: r, parallel-coordinates, ggally

My question is I want to change the line width of parallel coordinate according to a specific column, for example I want the record with `type==mean` become thicker than other individual lines. But it seems that `ggparcoord` does not have that option but only has the option to change the `alpha` of the line. Any idea about how to do this? maybe use `mapping` option?

A reproducible example could be

```
library(dplyr)
library(GGally)
mean_row = select(iris,-Species) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% mutate(Species="mean")
iris2 = rbind(mean_row,iris)
gpd <- ggparcoord(data = iris2, columns = 1:4, groupColumn = 5)
```

Comment: It would have been courteous to include the name of the package from which you were getting `ggparcoord`.

Comment: thx for the kind reminder! Please see the updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
gpd+geom_line(size=2)
```

Kind of an ugly plot but it does show that the "+"-function is being given an effective argument.
[image]

Comment: but I kind of want the size vary with the `Species` but not sure how to add this argument...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out thanks to the reminding of @BondedDust

```
gpd <- ggparcoord(data = iris2, columns = 1:4, groupColumn = 5)+geom_line(aes(size=ifelse(Species=="mean",2,0.1)))
```